# File does not upload properly

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

here I want to upload my file into my upload folder but in my scenario, it cannot store in that folder. The file name is printed in the console but the file does not store in the upload folder. In the Developer tool console, I get an error called Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found).

**DemoForm.java**

```
    package controller;

import java.io.*;


import java.util.* ;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.Part;



/**
 * Servlet implementation class DemoForm
 */
@WebServlet("/DemoForm")
@MultipartConfig(
        fileSizeThreshold = 1024 * 1024 * 10, //10MB
        maxFileSize = 1024 * 1024 * 50, //50MB
        maxRequestSize = 1024 * 1024 * 100 //100MB
        )

public class DemoForm extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final String UPLOAD_DIR = "upload";



    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public DemoForm() { 
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        request.setAttribute("username", request.getParameter("username"));
        request.setAttribute("password", request.getParameter("password"));
        request.setAttribute("sex", request.getParameter("sex"));
        request.setAttribute("favious", Arrays.toString(request.getParameterValues("favious")));
        request.setAttribute("description", request.getParameter("description"));
        request.setAttribute("experience", request.getParameter("experience"));
        request.setAttribute("fileName", uploadFile(request));
        request.getRequestDispatcher("form_result.jsp").forward(request, response);

    }

    private String uploadFile(HttpServletRequest request) {

        String fileName = "";

        try {
            Part filePart = request.getPart("photo");
            fileName = getfileName(filePart);
            String applicationPath = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("");
            String basePath = applicationPath + File.separator + UPLOAD_DIR 
                    + File.separator;
            // creates the save directory if it does not exists
            File fileSaveDir = new File(basePath);
            if (!fileSaveDir.exists()) {
                fileSaveDir.mkdir();
            }
            InputStream inputStream = null;
            OutputStream outputStream = null;
            try {
                File outputFilePath = new File(basePath + fileName);
                inputStream =filePart.getInputStream();
                outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFilePath);
                int read = 0;
                final byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
                while((read = inputStream.read(bytes))!= -1) {
                    outputStream.write(bytes,0,read);
                }
            }catch(Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                fileName="";

            }finally {
                if(outputStream != null) {
                    outputStream.close();
                }
                if(inputStream != null) {
                    inputStream.close();
                }
            }

        }catch(Exception ex){
            fileName = "";
        }
        return fileName;
    }


    private String getfileName(Part part) {
        final String partHeader = part.getHeader("content-disposition");
        System.out.println("*****partHeader:" + partHeader);
        for(String content : part.getHeader("content-disposition").split(";")) {
            if(content.trim().startsWith("fileName")) {
                return content.substring(content.indexOf('=')+ 1).trim()
                        .replace("\"", "");
            }
        }
        return null;
    }



}
```

**Form.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Upload file</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="DemoForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" width="300">
            <tr>
                <td> username:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="username"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> Password:</td>
                <td><input type="password" name="password"/></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td valign="top"> Sex </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" checked="checked"/>Male
                    <br>
                    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female"/>Female
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td valign="top"> Favious </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="favious" value="fav1"/>Favios 1<br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="favious" value="fav2"/>Favios 2<br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="favious" value="fav1"/>Favios 3<br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="favious" value="fav1"/>Favios 4<br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="favious" value="fav1"/>Favios 5<br>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td valign="top"> Description:</td>
                <td><textarea rows="10" cols="20" name="description"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Experiences</td>
                <td>
                    <select name="experience">
                        <option value="1"> 1 year </option>
                        <option value="2"> 2 year </option>
                        <option value="3"> 3 year </option>
                        <option value="4"> 4 year </option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td valign="top"> Photo</td>
                <td><input type="file" name="photo "/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp</td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="save"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Form_result.jsp**

```
[<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@page isELIgnored="false" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
        <h3>Account Information</h3>
        <table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" width="300">
            <tr>
                <td>Username</td>
                <td> ${username}</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Password</td>
                <td> ${password}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td valign="top">Sex</td>
                <td> ${sex}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td valign="top">Favious</td>
                <td> ${favious}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td valign="top">Description</td>
                <td> ${description}</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Experience</td>
                <td> ${experience}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td valign="top">Photo</td>
                <td><img src="upload/${fileName}"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
</body>
</html>][1]
```

Comment: The getRealPath method returns a path with a trailing slash. So, you could try String basePath = applicationPath + UPLOAD_DIR Also, I should mention that the Part interface has the getSubmittedFileName() method and that the java.nio.file.Files class has the copy static method.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is not in your file uploading. Your request has not been received by your servelet. Just comment out all the codes and check whether your doPost is working or not? Check the URL you are hitting.

Comment: doPost function is working because other values are getting into the form_result.jsp page correctly

Answer (score 0):

The endpoint on which you are trying to upload the file is invalid.

Errorcode 404 means that the endpoint can not be found.

Comment: first, my file must upload to upload folder directory. that's a problem now. file does not upload correctly. if the file is uploaded successfully that endpoint is correct